# learnyounode - async juggling - Duplicate results of http.get()

Tags: javascript, node.js

Doing a tutorial on learnyounode, I encountered the following problem. From the description:

> You will be provided with three URLs as the first three command-line arguments. You must collect the complete content provided to you by each of the URLs and print it to the console (stdout). You don't need to print out the length, just the data as a String; one line per URL. The catch is that you must print them out in the same order as the URLs are provided to you as command-line arguments.

It seems that some of the time I get duplicate results for one of the urls provided, however, at other times the code passes the tests that the authors of the tutorial have created...

```
http = require('http')

var urls = process.argv.slice(2)

var output = []

// allocate space for the contents of each response.
output.length = urls.length

var counter = 0

urls.forEach( function(url, index, array) {

    http.get(url, function (response) {

        stream = ''

        response.on("error", function (error) {
            console.error('There was an error:', err)
        })

        response.on("data", function (data) {
            stream = stream + data.toString();
        })

        response.on("end", function () {
            // it seems that this even fires multiple times for the same url (?)
            output.splice(index, 1, stream);

            counter += 1;

            if (counter == array.length) {
                output.forEach( function (element, index, array) {
                    console.log(element);

                })
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By failing to initialize `stream` with `var`, you've made it a global variable.  This means that each request is trying to initialize as `''` and then accumulate data in the same variable.  Depending on the order in which the responses come back and the events are fired, you'll get all sorts of nonsense as output.